# axios response 404 on nuxt.js, MAMP server

Tags: api, apache, axios, nuxt.js

im working on nuxt.js project. the axios request(reach to AWS api server) is well working on development mode. however after nuxt run build, the axios cannot find apache server(comes up 404err). I using my MAMP local server and take directory to .nuxt/dist/
info: its not a CORS issue i already solved it before

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsfNo.png)